# Projecting raster layer from GCS_North_American_1983 to UTM Zone 11N

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, arcmap

I want to reproject a raster from GCS_North_American_1983 to UTM Zone 11N. I looked up how to do this on Google and based on those searches and reading the Esri website, I used the "project" tool in ArcToolbox. (Data management tools > projections and transformations > raster > project). However, when I open this tool, the first box in the window "input dataset or feature class" does not list my raster layer as one I can select. I am really confused by this because when I googled *change raster projection arcmap* the exact directions I got were to use this tool.

Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

I solved my own problem. I was clicking on the Project tool instead of the Project Raster tool. The Project Raster tool is in a place on the toolbox I did not see.